# How can I show an empty view in place of a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I have a UITableViewController. When a certain BOOL is set, I want to show another view instead of the UITableView. How can I do this? I need to be able to bring the UITableView back also.

Comment: Where are you setting the bool?

Comment: I have a UIBarButtonItem that toggles it

Answer (score 9):

I implemented the following method in my Table view controller subclass to reload its background.

```
- (void)reloadBackground
{

        if(myBool)
        {

    //load the view to be displayed from a nib        
    NSArray* nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EmptyView" owner:self options:nil];
            UIView* emptyView = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
            self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyView;
            self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        }
        else
        {
            self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
            self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
        }

}
```

HTH,

Akshay

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `UITableViewController`, you can put two views inside a `UIViewController`:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {
   UITableView *tableView;
   UIWebView *anotherView;
}
```

...

```
if (someBool) {
   tableView.hidden = YES;
   anotherView.hidden = NO;
} else {
   tableView.hidden = NO;
   anotherView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about..

```
if(myBOOL == YES) {

   ADifferentViewController * vc = (ADifferentViewController *)[[ADifferentViewController alloc]init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
   [vc release];

}
```

Comment: I don't want to push a view controller onto the stack. I just want to replace the current view.

Comment: The ask is to set the background of the Table View, and not push another view on top of it.

Comment: Oh sorry.. misread the question. Whoever downvoted dont be so fkin critical. sh!t!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like:

```
if (myBool == YES) {

 UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
 [self.view addSubview:myView];

}
```

Now to get rid of it:

```
[myView removeFromSuperview];
```

Of course there are plenty of other methods...

Even: `self.view = myView;`

Answer (score 0):

> Use a UIView instead if UITableViewController.... from .h file change
>   UITableViewController to UIViewController Connect view to Files owner
>   from xib
>
> take UITableView in a UIView... take another UIView for a blank view
>   and set its background color as Tableview color
>
> If your bool if true
>       then show tableview 
>       and  hide blank View else 
>        hide tableview
>        show blank view